# git push throws error "tip of current branch is behind"

Tags: git, version-control, push, cloudcontrol

I got a local app. The push to my host cloudcontrol.com doesn´t work. The terminal says that I have to pull and push it again. But the commands were not recognized and errors are thrown. My approach:

1) I used to git `init` my repository, then `git add *` everything, `git commit -m "first commit"`, then `cctrlapp appname push`and `cctrlapp appname deploy`
Note: cctrlapp is a shortcut for the service at cloudcontrol.com which uses git internally.
That first deployment went great, the site was shown on the server.

2) On my local system I deleted the index.html manually and added some files in the folders. Furthermore I changed the folder structure.
3) I tried to deploy the changes with the same comands as shown in 1). After doing the command `cctrlapp appname push` it fails with the errors: [image: errors in terminal]

I hope you have an idea how to fix it :) Thanks

Comment: Try a `git pull`, i.e. not using your `cctrlapp` tool.

Comment: `git pull appname` says that appname not appears to be a git repository :(

Comment: Not `git pull appname` but just `git pull`. If that does not work, please see if `git remote -v` shows any remotes.

Comment: You either have to setup the remote by hand or use git pull ssh://APPNAME@cloudcontrolled.com/repository.git